# Tools to build interactive dashboards

Tags: .net, reporting-services, reporting, dashboard

What software are you using to build interactive dashboards? We're a Microsoft .NET shop, so ideally we're interested in MS tools. Our data is in SQL Server database. Can SSRS be used for that? Where can I see some examples?

Answer (score 0):

SSRS can be used to build dashboards, but they aren't as interactive and visually appearing as some third party tool.  Take a look at Domo, iDashboards, or Microstrategy as they are some pretty popular reporting/dashboard tools.

If you want to use the tools you already have, take a look at how to work with drilldowns in reports (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519554.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, Brewster! iDashboard looks great, but is written in Java -- this may be an issue for us. Domo seems to be more user-oriented, allowing end users to do their own reports/dashboards. Microstrategy -- I am still thinking about it, too comprehensive product it seems... Drilldown reports in SSRS look interesting.

Comment: Drilldown with SSRS will be the easiest without any necessary third party tools.  It depends on what you need to be able to do, but it does have enough capabilities to complete most basic dashboarding tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Though not an MS tool, you may take a look at [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com), it offers various ways of consuming data, then provides query language, interactive reporting and dashboarding capabilities, and also custom application and add-on development layer on top of its standard UI.

Comment: Never thought about using Splunk in such a way. Thanks, will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Sure SSRS can be used for that, but if you want something better, you may also want to consider third party tools, there are several and you can try most of them for a limited time, as you don't say if you have a requirements list for your dashboards, i recommend you to try as much tools as you can an pick up the one that's easier to use and cover your needs, for example, you can start, with [DBxtra](http://dbxtra.com/), which makes creating dashboards, from query to final design, an easy task.

P.S.: I'm a DBxtra evangelist.